# Why is my UITableView rowNumber zero?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my `DetailViewController.m`, the `rowNumber` value is functioning well. But when the value can't apply into `viewDidLoad` the `rowNumber` is zero. How can I solve this problem?

```
//DetailViewController.m

    -(void)updateRowNumber:(int)theindex
    {
        rowNumber = theindex + 1;
        message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d was clicked", rowNumber];
        NSLog(@"ID #000%d", rowNumber);
    }

    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d was clicked", rowNumber];
    }
```

Comment: What does "when the value can't apply into" mean?

Comment: Like i select row 1 in viewController, the DetailViewController will display "row 1 was clicked"
but now the DetailViewController is display "row 0 was clicked" while the output of nslog is "ID#001"

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but its obvious that you should be using the tableview delegate methods:

It looks like you really need the method below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You'd want to store the rowNumber with this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   int rowNumber = indexPath.row;
}
```

Or, if the row is still selected and you want to grab that index somewhere else you could do:

```
NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
int rowNumber = index.row;
```

But check out all the methods on the dev site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: - (void)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (dvController == nil) {
        DetailViewController *aController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
        
        self.dvController = aController;
    }
    
    [dvController updateRowNumber:indexPath.row];
    
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:detail animated:YES completion:nil];
}
i done this, i wan pass the value of "(void)updateRowNumber:(int)theindex" to the rowNumber of ViewDidLoad

Comment: Look at the snippet i just posted

Comment: the rowNumber is use to calculate the number of row of the table view, i use NSLog(@"ID #000%d", rowNumber); can show the value while when i launch the apps, the value is 0
for example, i click row 4 the NSLog will display "ID #0004", but the interface didn't show the value

Comment: dude u just use [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] for that..piece of cake

Comment: the table is on viewController, when i select the row, its will display on the DetailViewController. Like i select row 1 in viewController, the DetailViewController will display "row 1 was clicked"

Comment: That english does not make any sense but it sounds like you want to pass the value to another viewController. Pass it inside of prepareForSegue

Comment: Try this:
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NextViewController *nvc = (NextViewController *)[mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextVC"];
    [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];